# SonarQube Unable to create symbol table value already present: null

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

I have just configured my Jenkins 2.10 with Sonar 5.6 (Java plugin v. 3.14), every time I run a jenkins job Sonar also runs and the build is successful. But many of the metrics are simply missing, upon inspecting the logs I have:

```
    ERROR: Unable to create symbol table for : /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/EnaparkServer/core/src/main/java/br/com/enapark/core/ApplicationConfig.java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value already present: null
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:115) ~[sonar-plugin-api-deps1846330885217473608jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractBiMap.putInBothMaps(AbstractBiMap.java:112) ~[sonar-plugin-api-deps1846330885217473608jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractBiMap.put(AbstractBiMap.java:96) ~[sonar-plugin-api-deps1846330885217473608jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.put(HashBiMap.java:85) ~[sonar-plugin-api-deps1846330885217473608jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.Symbols.<init>(Symbols.java:189) ~[java-frontend-3.14.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel.createFor(SemanticModel.java:56) ~[java-frontend-3.14.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:112) ~[java-frontend-3.14.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:84) [java-frontend-3.14.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:67) [java-frontend-3.14.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:143) [java-frontend-3.14.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:136) [java-frontend-3.14.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:95) [sonar-java-plugin-3.14.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62) [sonar-scanner-api-batch6466690605100887981.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-internal/Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-internal/Method.java:531) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60) [sonar-scanner-cli-2.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:240) [sonar-scanner-cli-2.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151) [sonar-scanner-cli-2.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110) [sonar-scanner-cli-2.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:72) [sonar-scanner-cli-2.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:60) [sonar-scanner-cli-2.6.1.jar:na]
```

And that is repeated for each and every one of my classes.

Comment: What is the question? Post some configs that you suspect in incorrect processing? Maybe refer to the documentation that you use to setup Jenkins + Sonar?